# How to handle event when tab circle is moving left direction anticlockwise

Tags: javascript, jquery

Reference : https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_document.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_doc_readystate.asp

This is my code:

```
document.onreadystatechange = function () {
    var state = document.readyState
    if (state == 'interactive') { /* Here I changed state with 'uninitialized', 'loading', 'loaded' but doesn't work. Only 'interactive' works when chrome tab loading circle moves right direction 'clockwise' but still not what I want*/
        $("body").css("opacity", "0.5");
        $("body").css("background-color", "pink");
    } 
    else if (state == 'complete') { /*works fine*/
        $("body").css("opacity", "0.5");
        $("body").css("background-color", "blue");
    }
}
```

What I want is e.g when I refresh a page and when tab circle is moving left direction 'anticlockwise' it should show pink. and blue on complete. On complete it works fine. I just don't know how to turn it pink when its moving 'anticlockwise'. As I believe all in browser events Javascript can handle.

Will appreciate if there is any solution.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed by doing this:

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
  $("body").css("opacity", "0.5");
  $("body").css("background-color", "pink");
});

document.onreadystatechange = function () {
    var state = document.readyState 
    if (state == 'complete') {
        $("body").css("opacity", "0.5");
        $("body").css("background-color", "blue");
    }
}
```